# AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'

Tags: python

```
>>> import attr
>>> @attr.s
... class SmartClass(object):
...     a=attr.ib()
...     b=attr.ib()
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'
>>>
```

I don't understand why it's not working. I have installed this module using pip and it was installed properly, but still it shows an error in the implementation part.

Comment: Which version of Python you have use ?

Comment: By any chance, have you put this code (or some other `attr`-using code) into a script named `attr.py` that's sitting in your current working directory?

Comment: pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (python 3.5)

Comment: Or, have you also installed `attrs`?

Comment: Don't you have to use @attrs before the class definition? That makes it work for me

Comment: If you are trying to test the sample code, then you missed the decorator.

Comment: I'm using python shell @abarnert

Comment: @AbhijeetKumar: I'm not sure which comment that's supposed to be a reply to; it doesn't seem to answer any of them.

Comment: even after using @attrs before the class it showing the same, I just have edited my question

Comment: Even though I don't love the PEP 557 design, I can't wait for it to be in the stdlib so novices don't need to install `attrs` and run into this `attr` vs. `attrs` confusion anymore…

Answer (score 124, accepted):

The [`attr`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attr) library on PyPI does not have an API that looks like this. There's no `attr.ib` or `attr.s` in it, and so no reason you should expect it to work.

You're probably using documentation for the [`attrs`](http://www.attrs.org/) library, which—somewhat confusingly—installs packages named both `attrs` and `attr`, and does in fact have an `attr.s` and an `attr.ib`, used exactly the way you're attempting.

But if you want to use the `attrs` library, you have to install it—and you probably want to uninstall `attr` too:

```
$ pip uninstall attr
$ pip install attrs
```

(If you actually want both, it's a bit confusing; the recommended way seems to be to use `attr` from `attrs`, and `dry_attr` from `attr`.)

Of course the best solution is to hop in a time machine to a few months in the future so you can use Python 3.7, with its [PEP 557](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-557-data-classes) data classes, a feature based largely on `attrs`, but simpler and built in to the stdlib.

Comment: I'm from future, from 2021, I have Python 3.7 installed, but it doesn't seem to have `attr` built-in, but having to run: `pip uninstall attr` then `pip uninstall attrs` then `pip install attrs`, - seems to resolve the issue. Thx

Comment: The solution by Jerry Green worked for me in June 2022.

Comment: In 2023 on Python 3.10.8, this does not work for me. I have `attrs` installed already and don't have `attr` installed, but still get the same error while debugging in PyCharm

Comment: I'm from future using conda, from 2023. I have Python 3.10.6 installed, but it doesn't seem to have `attr` built-in, but having to run: `pip uninstall attr attrs` then `conda install attrs --force-reinstall --update-deps`, seems to do the trick. Thx

Answer (score -6):

```
$ python3 -c 'import attr; print(attr.__file__)'
/path/to/python3.X/site-packages/attr.py
```

Removing this file worked for me. So

```
rm $(python3 -c 'import attr; print(attr.__file__)')
```

solves the issue.

Comment: With no other information whatsoever this isn't helpful, but it did solve my issue with my jupyterhub server being able to start!