# django runserver returns error when i run py manage.py runserver on a project my friends did how can i resolve this issue?

Tags: python, mysql, django, migration, django-migrations

I wanted to open a Django file my friends did and I installed Django MySQL client etc.. but run server doesn't work, it works when I run my own other file so here's the error and SQL code
I pip installed MySQL connector As well but it still didn't change anything do you guys have any suggestions to why the run server is encountering this problem?

```
C:\Users\user>pip install mysql-connector-python
Requirement already satisfied: mysql-connector-python in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (8.0.28)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.0.0 in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from mysql-connector-python) (3.19.4)

C:\Users\user>pip install pillow
Collecting pillow
  Downloading Pillow-9.0.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (3.2 MB)
     ---------------------------------------- 3.2/3.2 MB 494.0 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pillow
Successfully installed pillow-9.0.1

C:\Users\user>py manage.py makemigrations
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\\Users\\user\\manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\user>cd documents\one_art

C:\Users\user\Documents\one_art>py manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 87, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 248, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration gallery.0008_artist_buyer_selllog_stat_alter_artwork_artist_and_more dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\one_art\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\one_art\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 230, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 261, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 380, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable

C:\Users\user\Documents\one_art>py manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 87, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 248, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration gallery.0008_artist_buyer_selllog_stat_alter_artwork_artist_and_more dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\one_art\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\one_art\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 341, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 230, in close_all
    connection.close()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 261, in close
    if not self.is_in_memory_db():
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 380, in is_in_memory_db
    return self.creation.is_in_memory_db(self.settings_dict['NAME'])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\creation.py", line 12, in is_in_memory_db
    return database_name == ':memory:' or 'mode=memory' in database_name
TypeError: argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
```

the file runs on my friends computer but not mine

the sql code:-

```
    create user one_art_admin identified by 'Horriblebob11';
    grant all on one_art.* to one_art_admin;
    flush privileges;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of Traceback, it is not  SQL client issue. It is an error of missing library attr.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attr'
```

you can refer to this link to resolve the issue.
[ImportError: No module named attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729841/importerror-no-module-named-attr)

Answer (score 0):

It says attr module not found
Try to install the module:

```
     pip install attr
```

Then run again.