# failing to launch jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I have tried every thing right from conda-clean, re-installing anaconda sevral times, even cleaned windows registry to completely remove anaconda before re-installation. Every time I am trying to launch jupyter notebook a pop-up opens with msg

> (Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\anaconda\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in from notebook.notebookapp import main File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 83, in from .services.contents.manager import ContentsManager File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\contents\manager.py", line 17, in from nbformat import sign, validate as validate_nb, ValidationError File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\nbformat__init__.py", line 33, in from .validator import validate, ValidationError File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\nbformat\validator.py", line 12, in from jsonschema import ValidationError File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jsonschema__init__.py", line 12, in from jsonschema.exceptions import ( File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jsonschema\exceptions.py", line 141, in @attr.s(hash=True) AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's')

Kindly help for the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228744/attributeerror-module-attr-has-no-attribute-s
不知道这个是否能起到作用

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228744/attributeerror-module-attr-has-no-attribute-s this maybe help,it seems your attrs module have problem.