# Attribute error in Python while using pandas_profiling

Tags: python, attributeerror, pandas-profiling

I am using Pandas-profiling to generate a report for my data. The code is as follows

```
# importing the library
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

# getting a small subset and passing into ProfileReport constructor
sub = general_data.head()
ProfileReport(sub)
```

This seems to throw a completely unrelated error about the attr module. That it does not have an attribute "s". I understand there are two different modules attr and attrs and that the later has s as an
attribute. This is the link that talks about that, [AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228744/attributeerror-module-attr-has-no-attribute-s)

Thanks a lot for the help.

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
             AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
      2 sub = general_data.head()
----> 3 ProfileReport(sub)

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\__init__.py in __init__(self, df, minimal, config_file, **kwargs)
     68 
     69         # Get dataset statistics
---> 70         description_set = describe_df(df)
     71 
     72         # Build report structure

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\model\describe.py in describe(df)
    600             with multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool(pool_size) as executor:
    601                 for i, (column, description) in enumerate(
--> 602                     executor.imap_unordered(multiprocess_1d, args)
    603                 ):
    604                     series_description[column] = description

D:\anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in next(self, timeout)
    746         if success:
    747             return value
--> 748         raise value
    749 
    750     __next__ = next                    # XXX

D:\anaconda\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in worker(inqueue, outqueue, initializer, initargs, maxtasks, wrap_exception)
    119         job, i, func, args, kwds = task
    120         try:
--> 121             result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
    122         except Exception as e:
    123             if wrap_exception and func is not _helper_reraises_exception:

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\model\describe.py in multiprocess_1d(args)
    386     """
    387     column, series = args
--> 388     return column, describe_1d(series)
    389 
    390 

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\model\describe.py in describe_1d(series)
    366         if series_description["type"] in type_to_func:
    367             series_description.update(
--> 368                 type_to_func[series_description["type"]](series, series_description)
    369             )
    370         else:

D:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling\model\describe.py in describe_categorical_1d(series, series_description)
    163         stats["min_length"] = series.str.len().min()
    164 
--> 165         from visions.application.summaries.series.text_summary import text_summary
    166 
    167         stats.update(text_summary(series))

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\visions\__init__.py in 
----> 1 from visions import core
      2 from visions import utils
      3 
      4 from visions.core.dtypes.boolean import BoolDtype
      5 from visions.core.implementations.types import *

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\visions\core\__init__.py in 
----> 1 from visions.core import model
      2 from visions.core import implementations
      3 from visions.core.functional import (
      4     type_cast_frame,
      5     type_inference_frame,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\visions\core\model\__init__.py in 
----> 1 from visions.core.model.type import VisionsBaseType, TypeRelation
      2 from visions.core.model import typeset
      3 from visions.core.model.typeset import VisionsTypeset

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\visions\core\model\type.py in 
     38 
     39 
---> 40 @attr.s(frozen=True)
     41 class TypeRelation:
     42     """Relationship encoder between implementations of :class:`visions.core.models.VisionsBaseType`

AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's' here
```

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this issue occurred with a previous version of `pandas-profiling`. Updating to the latest version resolves the issue.