# Cannot start Label-Studio after installing it with Anaconda

Tags: python, path, package, anaconda, label-studio

I tried to downgrade the last version of Label-Studio to 1.4.0 in an attempt to solve the issue. Could it be an issue with PATH and/or environment variables?
This is the full error I get when entering the command `label-studio` in the Anaconda Prompt (executed as Admin) :

```
Current platform is win32, apply sqlite fix
Can't load sqlite3.dll from current directory
=> Database and media directory: C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\label-studio\label-studio
=> Static URL is set to: /static/
Starting new HTTPS connection (1): pypi.org:443
https://pypi.org:443 "GET /pypi/label-studio/json HTTP/1.1" 200 56465

   ╔═════════════════════════════════════╗
   ║                                     ║
   ║   Update available 1.4 → 1.7.3      ║
   ║   Run pip install -U label-studio   ║
   ║                                     ║
   ╚═════════════════════════════════════╝

NumExpr defaulting to 8 threads.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts\label-studio.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\label_studio\server.py", line 282, in main
    _setup_env()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\label_studio\server.py", line 40, in _setup_env
    application = get_wsgi_application()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\label_studio\users\models.py", line 18, in <module>
    from projects.models import Project
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\label_studio\projects\models.py", line 14, in <module>
    from tasks.models import Task, Prediction, Annotation, Q_task_finished_annotations, bulk_update_stats_project_tasks
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\label_studio\tasks\models.py", line 28, in <module>
    from core.label_config import SINGLE_VALUED_TAGS
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\label_studio\core\label_config.py", line 9, in <module>
    import jsonschema
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\jsonschema\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from jsonschema.exceptions import (
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\jsonschema\exceptions.py", line 152, in <module>
    @attr.s(hash=True)
AttributeError: module 'attr' has no attribute 's'
```

Comment: You seem to have a conflicting python version sitting in `C:\Users\pc\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310`, also with a label studio installation. Can you try uninstalling that?

Answer (score 0):

Try following this instructions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49228822/1045399

```
$ pip uninstall attr
$ pip install attrs
```

This one could be helpful too:
https://github.com/HumanSignal/label-studio/issues/4042